# Jquery: How to add an image to a remove button

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, button

I'm working on a class project to create a shopping list in jquery. I'm struggling with two similar issues.

As you can see from the image, I have an "Add" button and a remove "X" which both function a they should.

I'm trying to replace both of these objects with images I have created in Adobe Illustrator, the first a "plus +" icon and the second a "minus -" icon.

Any advice is much appreciated.

[Shopping List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMcJs.png)

```css
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#input-form").submit(function() {
  var newItem = $("#input-item").val();

  if (newItem.length > 0) {

   var listItem = "<li>";
   listItem += "<input type='checkbox'>";
   listItem += "<span>" + newItem + "</span>";
   listItem += "<span class='remove'>X</span>";
   listItem += "</li>";

   $("#items").append(listItem);
  }
  return false;
 })

})

$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
 $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="main">
  <header>
   <h1>Shopping List</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="input">
   <form id="input-form">
    <input id="input-item" type ="text">
    <button type="submit">add</button>
   </form>
  </div>
  <div id="list">
   <ul id="items">
    <!-- Items will go here -->
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing a submit button with a image button using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202075/replacing-a-submit-button-with-a-image-button-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `<button>` tag for add and `<span>` for remove.
In any case, you can add image by:

```
<button type="submit"><img src="your/image/url"/></button>
<span class="remove"><img src="your/image/url"/></span>
```